# Simplest way to store and populate data for a demo application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am currently creating an application that has a user, the user can follow others, post content, amongst a few other features and am wondering what would be the most ideal way to store and create data for a demo. I started building a rails site but felt that is becoming fairly time consuming for a demo application. Does anyone have any suggestions? pLists, JSON file, XML files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the nature and size of the data?

- pLists are convenient for a few dozen lines since they are easily converted into a dictionary at runtime.
- If you have hundreds of items, you're probably better off writing an xml file and parsing it.

Comment: Yeah, it'll only be a few dozen results for each "table" of results. I think pLists are the best option.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way is to way the object to **FILE** use Keyed Archiving. If you are bored about right almost same Keyed Archiving code each time. try to use [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html)